# mysql LONGBLOB displaying whats in the file, not the file name

Tags: sql, database

How do I make the LONGBLOB field in the SQL database only display the filename and extension on the webpage? Right now I've uploaded multiple text files and its showing whats inside the files, not what its called

http://cpdonline.tv/testing-files/events/index.php

Above is the link to the page

Comment: You have to check how your system is defined. It probably stores the files on that fields. BLOB are fields to store large objects as bytes. If your system was designed to this kind of things it probably have somewhere else the file name stored in another field for example. If who designed it didn't create a column to place the file names, i'm sorry this is a lost information for your system. Also do not link your system directly into questions. Just add some part of it right here on your post.

Comment: I created the system, I used LONGBLOB in the hope of storing PowerPoint presentations that would be downloadable (further down the line) so all i wanted was to display the name of the file. 

Is it possible that i could just change the type field in the DB?

Comment: If your intent was to store the files in the database that is fine, what you didn't know is that stored in the database are only the CONTENTS of the file, all the rest is lost, like created date, filename, file attributes. When we create a system like this usually we also include metadata columns to store this kind of information. If you didn't, you lost it. Changing the column type would not solve your problem, in fact will create another one, you will lose the stored files for good. So I recommend that you create such metadata fields and give it values for what you already have. And make...

Comment: Your system to fill those information once a file is uploaded.

Comment: Ok, thank you :) I will give it a go